# Infer generic types on scala shell

Tags: scala, type-inference, interactive-shell

Is it possible to use the scala shell to infer the type of a generic function?

I was trying to undestand the type of the function Future.traverse (scala 2.10). The complete generic type is

```
def traverse[A, B, M[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]](in: M[A])(fn: A => scala.concurrent.Future[B])(implicit cbf: generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[B]]
```

which is a long enough to be almost unreadable to me, So I thought it would be a good idea to try it is some more specific types. So I tried:

```
> :t (x : List[_]) => (Future traverse x) _
List[_] => ((Any => scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing]) => scala.concurrent.Future[List[Nothing]])
```

Which helped a lot, but it would be better if I could specify the type inside the List type constructor:

> :t (x : List[a]) => (Future traverse x) _

Which unfortunately (and comprehensibly) gives me a `type a not found` error.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
scala> object Foo {
     | type A = Int
     | type B = Int
     | }
defined object Foo

scala> import Foo._
import Foo._

scala> :type  Future.traverse[A,B,List] _
List[Foo.A] => ((Foo.A => scala.concurrent.Future[Foo.B]) => scala.concurrent.Future[List[Foo.B]])
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I needed.